# Server response not compressed in gRPC

Tags: grpc, gzip, grpc-java

This is my gRPC server

```java
public class GrpcServer {


        compressionServerInterceptor = new CompressionServerInterceptor();
        queueLimitingInterceptor = new QueueLimitingInterceptor(executor.getQueue(), MAX_QUEUE_SIZE);

        server = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(...)
                .channelType(...)
                .bossEventLoopGroup(...)
                .workerEventLoopGroup(...)
                .executor(...)
                .maxConnectionAge(...)
                .maxConnectionAgeGrace(...)
                // Enables client side reflection, for example in `grpcurl`
                // https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/server-reflection.md
                .addService(ProtoReflectionService.newInstance())
                .addService(ServerInterceptors.interceptForward(service, CompressionServerInterceptor))
                .addService(ServerInterceptors.interceptForward(service, queueLimitingInterceptor))
                .build();
    }
}
```

I am defining my compression interceptor as follows :

```java
public class CompressionServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    public class CompressionServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
                                                                 Metadata metadata,
                                                                 ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {

       String compressionAlgorithm = metadata.get(Metadata.Key.of("grpc-accept-encoding",
                Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER));
        // Check if the client supports compression
        if (compressionAlgorithm != null && compressionAlgorithm.contains("gzip")) {
            // Enable compression using Gzip algorithm
            serverCall.setMessageCompression(true);
            serverCall.setCompression("gzip");
        }
        // Forward the call to the next interceptor or the actual service implementation
        return serverCallHandler.startCall(serverCall, metadata);
    }
}
```

But my response sent from the server is not being compressed, I do not see a decrease in `netwrokTxByte`. What can I do?

I have verified that client request are compressed successfully.

_ I removed the queue interceptor to check if the two interceptors are creating a conflict

- I also tried to add interceptor as follows :

```java
     .intercept(new ServerInterceptor() {
          @Override
          public <ReqT, RespT> Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers,
              ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
            call.setCompression("gzip");
            return next.startCall(call, headers);
          }
        })
```

Comment: Unconditionally calling `serverCall.setCompression("gzip");` should be all that's needed, assuming the client supports compression. Can you print out/log the client's grpc-accept-encoding header?